# Img src relative path taking file protocol

Tags: html, image

I am having problem with an email template. I am setting the URL without any scheme, so kept it relative. In html source code it's forming as below. But when I checked the browser it's trying to get the image with **file**
protocol. So it's not loading the image at all. I can add the scheme while forming the URL at back end but I want to avoid this. Not sure if it's related to doc type, i am using HTML 5. With http url image is accessible.

> !DOCTYPE
>   html

HTML Code:

```
<img  src="//domain.test.com/XXX/XXX/YYY.jsp?type=Interleaved2Of5&amp;msg=911000016096553&amp;fmt=image/jpeg&amp;height=33&amp;res=48&amp;mw=.7&amp;gray=true&amp;wf=2.5&amp;hrp=bottom&amp;hrsize=20pt&amp;hrfont=verdana"  width="146" height="62" style="display: block; margin:0; padding: 0"/>
```

On  Browser:

```
file://domain.test.com/XXX/XXX/YYY.jsp??type=Inte…ght=33&res=48&mw=.7&gray=true&wf=2.5&hr.....
```

Comment: Did you try to write http:// before the url?

Comment: yes, I did that. It worked fine.